# Python curses mouse event on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I am attempting to retrieve a mouse event via python curses running on Mac OS X 10.10.3. I have been following another question ([Python curses.getmouse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254664/python-curses-getmouse)) which has a simple example, but it doesn't produce the expected results for me. I think this has something to do with my Terminal and/or OS, but I am unsure.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
import curses 

screen = curses.initscr() 
#curses.noecho() 
curses.curs_set(0) 
screen.keypad(1) 
curses.mousemask(1)

screen.addstr("This is a Sample Curses Script\n\n") 

while True:
    event = screen.getch() 
    if event == ord("q"):
        screen.addstr(20, 10, "Q") 
    if event == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        a = curses.getmouse()
        screen.addstr(20, 10, a)
    screen.refresh()

curses.endwin()
```

Does anyone have any idea why the curses.KEY_MOUSE event never seems to come up?

Edit: I have already checked the return value of mousemask, and when it's run initially it returns the tuple (1, 0), as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, Terminal.app does not itself support mouse events.  This question has been asked before, with the suggestion to use another terminal emulator.  Alternatively, there is at least one add-on programs which can help, as noted in *[Does OS X's terminal app support mouse?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/does-os-xs-terminal-app-support-mouse)* suggests iTerm and [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/), but also mentions [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) (an add-on).  The same information is given in *[Mac OS X Terminal: mouse support?](https://superuser.com/questions/125102/mac-os-x-terminal-mouse-support)*

The original question was asked and answered in June 2015.  Apple provided a more up-to-date `Terminal.app`, seen in *El Capitan* OSX (later renamed to macOS) 10.11, later that year, documented in ncurses as [nsterm-build361](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-nsterm-build361) (see note for [October 2015](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20151024)).

Comment: MacOS terminal.app seems to support mouse events as of 13th August 2021. Better edit the answer to reflect changes.

Comment: There's no need to alter the history, only clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The default terminal application on Mac OS X ("Terminal.app") doesn't support mouse events. You'll need to use another terminal application, like [iTerm](https://iterm2.com/), to get these events.

Comment: Is there some way to add support for mouse events in Terminal.app?